# is package bmpsize still needed

Tags: graphics, pdftex, xetex, luatex

To be honest, I do not really understand the documentation of the `bmpsize` package.

I have it on older sources but without reference why it was needed.
So my first question is why it is needed,
because seemingly all what I compile works fine without it.
Is the background maybe creating dvi files? or using htlatex or something?

The second question is why compilation with `xelatex` fails
if applied to this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bmpsize}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

The result is:

```
his is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022/TeX Live for SUSE Linux) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-24> (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty

Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.

) (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/oberdiek/bmpsize.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty))

! Package bmpsize Error: You need pdfTeX 1.30.0 or newer.

See the bmpsize package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.53   }{Package loading is aborted.}
                                     %
```

The core seems `! Package bmpsize Error: You need pdfTeX 1.30.0 or newer.`
Well, I do have pdftex much newer and `xelatex` does not rely on `pdftex`, does it?
So, does this hint mean, that bmpsize is needed for pdflatex only??
What about `lualatex`?

I checked the version of xelatex:

```
$ xelatex -version
XeTeX 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022/TeX Live for SUSE Linux)
kpathsea version 6.3.4
Copyright 2022 SIL International, Jonathan Kew and Khaled Hosny.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the XeTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the XeTeX source.
Primary author of XeTeX: Jonathan Kew.
Compiled with ICU version 72.1; using 72.1
Compiled with zlib version 1.2.13; using 1.2.13
Compiled with FreeType2 version 2.12.1; using 2.13.0
Compiled with Graphite2 version 1.3.14; using 1.3.14
Compiled with HarfBuzz version 6.0.0; using 7.1.0
Compiled with libpng version 1.6.39; using 1.6.39
Compiled with pplib version v2.05 less toxic i hope
Compiled with fontconfig version 2.14.2; using 2.14.2
```

Comment: What is your minimal example in tex-code?

Comment: you almost certainly do not need it but it should still work.  "lualatex (my new default) complains and even pdflatex complains." is not an error report anyone can debug. Please provide an example and show the exact error message

Comment: ok, 
```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bmpsize}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

Comment: that runs without error in pdf/lua latex, it gives a spurious error in xelatex that we could fix

Comment: https://github.com/ho-tex/pdftexcmds/issues/8

Comment: so did you have "complaints" from either luatex or pdftex, as stated in the question?

Answer (score 2):

You almost certainly do not need this, `graphicx` (or rather its use of `extractbb`) means most formats are handled.

However it should work.

The supplied file runs without error in pdflatex and lualatex but gives a spurious error in xelatex as `pdftexmds` failed to define a wrapper for `\filedump`

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\pdf@filedump#1#2#3{\filedump offset#1 length#2{#3}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{bmpsize}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Runs without error